# query to display count of corresponding each distinct word

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

There is a column in a table which can store up to 4000 characters. So for a given row, we need to write a query to display count of corresponding each distinct word in the sentence.

For e.g. the column has "Jack and Jill went up a hill. Jack came tumbling down"

```
Output :  
<Word> - <Count> 
Jack - 2 
Jill - 1
hill - 1
and - 1
a - 1
came - 1 ... and so on
```

Comment: tag your dbms please

Comment: I would say split the sentence to words, group by word, and count distinct sentences in which it appears. But in second thought this is a human language processing task.

Comment: @DavidAldridge  I haven't had any ideas to proceed. i'm completely new to operations on "sentences"

Comment: What database are you really using?  It seems unlikely that the data is stored in both Oracle and Teradata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , convert the words into rows and then group it.

In this query, we use a basic concept of row generation using `CONNECT BY`.

For Example:

```
select level from dual CONNECT BY level <= 10;
```

The above query would generate 10 rows.(Hierarchical Level query).

Based on this simple logic, now we have to count the number of spaces here, and generate that many rows.`REGEXP_COUNT(str,'[^ ]+')` would give the number of spaces in the sentence.

And using the level, extract a word from the sentence in each row. `REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'[^ ]+',1,level)` would do this.

You can play around with this query to handle other scenarios. Good Luck.

```
with tokenised_rows(str) as(
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR('Jack and Jill went up a hill. Jack came tumbling down','[^ ]+',1,LEVEL) 
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT('Jack and Jill went up a hill. Jack came tumbling down','[^ ]+')
)
select str,count(1) from tokenised_rows
group by str;
```

Comment: @PraneethBobba Kindly accept the answer, if it helped you

Comment: How do you know that space separates between words? This might as well be `;`, `,`, `.`

Comment: we have to replace the punctuations accordingly with empty or space.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged `Teradata` you can use `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE` for the tokenizing part. Just add more characters to the separators list:

```
with cte as
(select
    1 as keycol,
    'Jack and Jill went up a hill. Jack came tumbling down' as col)
select keycol, token, count(*) as cnt
FROM TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(cte.keycol, cte.col, 
            ' .,;:-?!()''"') -- list of separators
     RETURNS (keycol INTEGER,
              tokennum INTEGER,
              token VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
           ) AS d 
group by 1,2
order by 1, cnt desc
```

But counting words might be much more complicated, as it usually includes tokenizing, stemming and stop words.